# SQL Server 2008 transaction log issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, transaction-log

I am learning about SQL Server 2008. I have created a database with full backup mode and made a transaction without commit. In the system database info the `log_reuse_wait_desc` column is still has the value 'NOTHING'. But the tutorial which I am following shows that the value changes to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'. Am I missing any configuration changes?

Thanks
Prathap

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `log_reuse_wait_desc` column is only updated as a response to certain actions such as log backups, checkpoints and attempts of SQL Server to clear old VLFs. Most of the time this column is  accurate (or accurate enough to be useful). I once read an article about this behavior from an authoritative community member but I cannot find it right now.

Try performing a `CHECKPOINT` or a log backup. The column should be updated by that.